# How to remove malware flag from virustotal.com

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, boost, exe

I wrote own code, using C++ Win32 API and boost library. The code compiles to EXE application for windows. I can guarantee that it is malware free, but virustotal.com reports that 9 of 56 antivirus softwares will recognize the exe file as having malware.

I see no reason why this should happen. I noticed some time ago that compiling things with LCC-Win32 compiler raised some malware flags while compiling the same code with Visual C++ produced a clean EXE file, however now even Visual C++ produces EXE file which flags as malware at virustotal.

I can say that my build computer is not infected, since if I compile just Hello World code, or some other bigger application, then virustotal doesn't report any malware at all for the newly compiled exe, which it would if some crazy stuff happened behind my back.

Is there any way to get rid of the incorrect malware flags reported by virustotal? I mean, without changing my code (since I know it's clean, I wrote it). Can I report somewhere at virustotal that their virus test is broken? Do I have to contact all the antivirus companies whose antivirus triggers the flag individually, one by one, by email, asking them to fix their antivirus software? Is there any place where one can report a false positive?

Comment: Can you please provide details what type of malware these 9 antiviruses report? Also, have you narrowed it down to which call in boost causes this? What happens with "Hello World!" application with boost library still in link references?

Comment: Boost is probably used by a sizeable population of malware, which could lead to some antiviruses regarding boost object code as malicious. Boost is just so darn big that it could really be anything. Try compiling your code in release mode with Boost statically linked, which should prune any unused Boost code. Then see if it triggers a false positive.

Comment: @Kaslai that makes no sense. The argument is much stronger for the "non-malware" software. Also, by statically linking you're gonna get ***more*** of boost code inside the binary (the _binary_ is flagged, not the Boost DLLs).

Comment: @Tomas Try the divide and conquer method, selectively remove TUs from compilation until you find which one(s) trigger the flag. Keep in mind it's also possible that it's not directly triggered from any TU, of course (it could be a PE format thing, like a text segment growing past a particular size, or maybe you've embedded resources that actually trigger the flag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked in a leading antivirus company and couple of others. So trying to answer your questions.

> Is there any way to get rid of the incorrect malware flags reported by
>   virustotal?

Antiviruses basically check executable for few suspecious symptoms. For example malicious packer used, entry point obfuscation, suspicious instruction set used, header info compromised etc. They essentially do it around executable's initial set of bytes. If any of these being incorporated in your executable behind your sense, antivirus will trigger it as malicious. If you want to "get rid of malicious flags" you have to narrow down on what causing them (It could be anything like: A function call, a module, specific post processing etc.) and then simply try to remove that root cause from your application.

At least if you can tell what type of malware is being reported by each antivirus for your executable, it would be helpful mitigating the problem.

> I mean, without changing my code (since I know it's clean, I wrote
>   it).

Without changing the code if you thinking of editing directly executable binary to remove "those few flags", it's not simply that straight forward. (As your might have realized by reading what I written above on how antiviruses analyzes the file before they trigger it as malicious).

Also, you cannot claim that it's clean "because you wrote it". Because you actually code portion of it. May be there is third party library/component you are using unknowingly, which you are not aware it is causing to trigger the whole executable as malicious. (And moreover, if your system has been infected, your newly developed executable can get infected immediately after you build it. This happens behind your sense.)

> Can I report somewhere at virustotal that their virus test is broken?

In your case, this is called "false positive". This is what virustotal says on their faq about false positives:

***VirusTotal is detecting a legitimate software I have developed,
 please remove the detections***

*VirusTotal acts simply as an information aggregator, presenting
 antivirus results, file characterization tool outputs, URL scanning
 engine results, etc. VirusTotal is not responsible for false positives
 generated by any of the resources it uses, false positive issues
 should be addressed directly with the company or individual behind the
 product under consideration.*

*We can, however, help you in combatting false positives. VirusTotal
 has built an early warning system regarding false positives whereby
 developers can upload their software to a private store, such software
 gets scanned on a daily basis with the latest antivirus signatures.
 Whenever there is a change in the detections of any of your files, you
 are immediately notified in order to mitigate the false positive as
 soon as possible.*

> Do I have to contact all the antivirus companies whose antivirus
>   triggers the flag individually, one by one, by email, asking them to
>   fix their antivirus software? Is there any place where one can report a false positive?

Yes. As mentioned by virustotal in above faq, false positive issues
 should be addressed directly with the company or individual behind the
 product under consideration.